# How can I create multiple user in oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, toad

I am not very good at oracle. currently I'm trying to create multiple user using script(Toad Editor) but no luck.

I need to create multiple user FE:  abc,efg,hij,klm . So I can able to create 152 user at a time and each user should have schema with same name.

Here is what I use to create single user for oracle 10g.

```
create user abc identified by abc;
grant connect,dba,resource to abc;
```

Is there any solution?

Comment: Why don't you use excel for creating the statements? Write common strings in one column and append with user names in another column.

Comment: Why would you want to create 152 users that all have the DBA role?  That seems like a poor idea.  Using the `connect` and `resource` roles is also frowned upon-- you should really be creating roles that contain the set of privileges that you really want to grant.  `connect` and `resource` almost always have privileges that you don't want to grant and are missing privileges that you do.

Comment: yes we have to do manage different schema with user name

Answer (score 1):

Since the username is unique , you can create a temporary table and insert only the username in the table and run a select statement to retreive the dynamically built query and it will return you the script to run.

```
create table tuser(username varchar2(50));
insert <required value>;

select 'create user' || username ||' identified by ' || username || ' ;'  from tuser;
```

Output :

```
create userabc identified by abc ;
create userxyz identified by xyz ;
create userabz identified by abz ;
create userdbz identified by dbz ;

select 'grant connect,dba,resource to '|| username || ' ;' from tuser;
```

Output :

```
grant connect,dba,resource to abc ;
grant connect,dba,resource to xyz ;
grant connect,dba,resource to abz ;
grant connect,dba,resource to dbz ;
```

Comment: I have created the temp table and insert data. use this to see output `select 'create user' || username ||' identified by ' || username || ' ;'  from tuser;` but how to create user from there one by one

Comment: may have to use any loop?

Comment: just run the commands in the sqlwindow it will create the users

Comment: you can copy the entire output and run it in the toad window or sqlplus window and it will create the users